# Hive how query over a transformed variable; FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to query over a specific  formatted date:

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(datewithoutdash,
    '^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(.*)$','20\\1-\\2-\\3') 
    datewithdash 
     FROM table1 WHERE datewithdash < "2016-11-10";
```

Why I can't use **where** clause over the *new variable*?

I'm getting this error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 26:14 Invalid table
>   alias or column reference 'datewithdash': (possible column names are:
>   ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive doesn't know about the aliased column names in a select clause when its evaluating a where clause in the same query.  Unfortunately you either have to nest it, or duplicate the transformation function into the where clause:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(datewithoutdash,
    '^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(.*)$','20\\1-\\2-\\3') as datewithdash 
FROM 
     table1 
WHERE 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(datewithoutdash,
    '^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(.*)$','20\\1-\\2-\\3')  < "2016-11-10";
```

OR

```
select * from (
    SELECT 
        REGEXP_REPLACE(datewithoutdash,
        '^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(.*)$','20\\1-\\2-\\3') as datewithdash 
    FROM 
         table1 
    ) a
WHERE 
    datewithdash  < "2016-11-10";
```

Another note - that function is pretty nasty - you could probably use a build in hive function like:

```
to_date(unix_timestamp(datewithoutdash,'yyMMdd'))
```

instead - it might be clearer.

Comment: Heyyy great answer !! Thanks for the tips. The last one about to_date how can I use over the where clause ?

Comment: Unfortunately you need to put it in both the select and where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Hive can not recognize aliases. You will need to repeat the whole expression again.