# SemanticException[Error 10004] Invalid table alias or column reference

Tags: sql, hive, sas

I'm trying to take the records by the first row in each group by id. the row number is generated by the order of id. I have been keeping getting the same error[10004].

This hive script is built in SAS studio environment and the following is a segment of proc sql code:

dataset id_f contains variable x,y and z

```
execute (create temporary table event_id_f1 as
        select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) as rownum
        from id_f
                        group by id
                        having rownum = min(rownum)
        )
by df20;
```

> Error:  Execute error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 
>           [Error 10004]: Line 1:129 Invalid table alias or column reference 'rownum': (possible column names are: x,y,z)

Appreciate any help!

@bernie suggested that Hive does not recognize alias. How should I nest the alias to make it work? The code is in an execute statement too.
My attempt:

```
execute (create temporary table event_id_f1 as

        from (
             select *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) as rownum
             from id_f
              group by id
              having rownum = min(rownum) ) ranked
             WHERE ranked=1
             )
by df20;
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895485/hive-how-query-over-a-transformed-variable-failed-semanticexception-error-100

Comment: @bernie do you have any idea how to convert my current code to be a nested selection for the row number not be an alias? I attempted to convert it, not sure if it looks right. My first time coding in Hive. You can refresh the post to see my attempt.

Comment: @bernie just made some more edits..

Comment: I just posted the way I'd write it. Tell me if the system returns any other error.

Comment: @bernie I will you know by tomorrow not by work computer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My humble opinion is that the following SQL is problematic(taken from another answer):

```
select * 
from (
    select id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as rownum
    from id_f
    group by id 
) ranked
where ranked.rownum = 1
```

This query breaks into three phases:

First, `select id from id_f group by id`, which is equivalent to getting all the distinct `id`.

Then, a global windowing to `order by` these different ids and give each of them a row number.

Finally, the `where ranked.rownum = 1` filter makes the result set contain only one row:

```
minimal_id, 1
```

If that's really all you want, use `min` should be much better.

This question didn't make much sense to me at first glance. I guess what you're looking for is to `partition by id`, and within each partition, `order by something_else`, and then choose the row ranked first within those distinct partitions. If luckily my guess is right, I'd suggest sth like this:

```
select 
    * 
from (
    select 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id ORDER BY STH_ELSE) as rownum
    from id_f
) ranked
where ranked.rownum = 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by using min? Do you mean I should use having rownum = min(rownum)? Instead of using where at the end ?

Comment: Oh I think only extracting one min value is not enough, what I want is to extract the min row number within each ID group. Therefore there will be one row per distinct ID. @gaccio

Comment: I guess the order will be unnecessary since it is within the same ID? I think was confused first believed I had to assign order to row number by ID.

Comment: @lydias My provied SQL is for getting one row per distinct ID. And if you don't care about how those rows are ordered within each ID partition, then you are right, you may not need the `order by` part. Although, there's no obvious efficiency gain by eliminating `order by`, either case, one MR job will be launched.

Comment: Did these tips solve your problem ? Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: I'm at work now, testing it out the code will let you know by noon. Thank you so much!

Comment: for some reason my server does not generate a table after adding the row number. There were no errors. It maybe a compatibility problem with Hive since we are pulling hive tables to SAS environment. I'm looking into the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I'd write it. Let me know if there's any error:

```
execute (create temporary table event_id_f1 as
    select * 
    from (
        select id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as rownum
        from id_f
        group by id 
    ) ranked
    where ranked.rownum = 1         
) by df20;
```